# How to run npm scripts with forever.json?

Tags: npm, forever

I want to run an npm script (like `npm start`) using forever. I know this command:

```
forever start -c "npm start" /path/to/app/dir/
```

But how can I ad that into a json file like this

```
[
  {
    // App1
    "uid": "app1",
    "append": true,
    "watch": false,
    "script": "-c npm start", // doesn't work
    "sourceDir": "/path/to/app/dir"
  }
]
```

Comment: I maybe wrong in this but the script contains the entry point so I think it should be                                                          
 "script": "index.js",                                                         "sourceDir": "/home/myuser/app",                                  "logFile": "/home/myuser/logs/forever.log",                  "outFile": "/home/myuser/logs/out.log",                          "errFile": "/home/myuser/logs/error.log"

Comment: @SachinYadav Yes, that's how it should be, but I'm trying to figure out if I'm able to run `npm start` anywhere within that configuration.

Comment: Just wanted to be clear with this, so you want to use npm start in the script like this "script": "npm start"  right?

Comment: Yes, so that I can add most of my used apps to that json file and all I'll need to remember would be `forever start ./development.json` rather than running each one independently.

Comment: @SachinYadav Yes thanks +1

Comment: @SachinYadav yeah, I could only give your comment an upvote.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot add directly npm start to the script, as you already know that script attribute is only to specify the main entry point of your application, probably you need to use some args.

`"scripts" : { "start" : "node server.js" } }`

where server.js is :-

```
http.createServer(...).listen(process.env.npm_package_config_port)
```